# es6 equivalent of underscore findWhere

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, ecmascript-6

I am looking to find out how I would take underscore `_.findWhere` and turn it into es6 native javascript?

```
_.findWhere($scope.template, {id: $scope.approveTemplate})
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While [Lim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37301940/1678362) is great for the specific example you posted, this one should handle every usecase of `_.findWhere` :

```
function myFindWhere(array, criteria) {
    return array.find(item => Object.keys(criteria).every(key => item[key] === criteria[key]))
}
```

It returns the first item from the input array for which all defined properties of the criteria are matched (or `undefined` if there is no such item), which I believe is the contract of `_.findWhere`.

Here's how to use it to handle your example :

```
myFindWhere($scope.template, {id: $scope.approveTemplate})
```

And here are a few test case I used to test it :

> myFindWhere([{"a":0, "b":1}, {"a":1}, {"b":1}], {"a":0})
>   > Object {a: 0, b: 1}
>   myFindWhere([{"a":0, "b":1}, {"a":1}, {"b":1}], {"b":0})
>   > undefined
>   myFindWhere([{"a":0, "b":1}, {"a":1}, {"b":1}], {"b":1})
>   > Object {a: 0, b: 1}
>   myFindWhere([{"a":0, "b":1}, {"a":1}, {"b":2}], {"b":2})
>   > Object {b: 2}

Comment: Thanks for the unit tests! :)

Answer (score 14):

```
$scope.template.find(t => t.id === $scope.approveTemplate)
```

Comment: @maskedbacon See the [documentation of the `find()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). Essentially, the method takes a callback function that determines which array element matches the search. In this example the callback is defined as an [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).